# Content Store - Information on secured functions and features of Cognos

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

Does anyone know where in Content Store database we can find information on secured functions and features (Administration, Execute Indexed Search etc.) that are granted to users / groups / roles? In other words I want to write a SQL query to get users / groups / roles that have access to particular secured functions and features.

Manual checks CMOBJPROPSN, CMREFORDN and CMREFNOORDN had no result for me.

We use Cognos BI 10.2.1.

Comment: You'll probably need to use the SDK for something like this.  The content store is intentionally not documented.

Comment: Hello Andrew. I understand that Content Store is intentionally not documented. That's why I'm asking question here and not filing PMR with IBM.

Answer (score 2):

There are specialised tools for that (its not obvious how to get information out of cognos db). I am not sure if [MotioPI](http://www.motio.com/content/motiopi-cognos-administration-tools) can help here, but you might try it. I used it in the past, for some admin tasks, and it was useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can query what users are assigned to what groups/roles.  You can go into the Cognos Administration to determine what capabilities are assigned to the roles.

(Example for query against Oracle Content Store)

```
-- To run on Cognos Prod Content Store, to check for Cognos Group assignments
select --decode(cmo.classid, 26, 'Role', 54, 'Group', 'Other') "OBJECT_TYPE"
      cmon.name object_name
,     v_user.name user_name
--,      cmo.cmid  object_cmid, v_user.cmid user_cmid
--,      cmr.propid                                            -- cmreford1.propid: ??? so far, always 27 for group/role assignments, 22/23/25 for timestamps?, 5 for report names?, 28 for Datasources, 45 large hex strings?
--,      cmr.ord                                               -- cmreford1.ord: order the user has when displaying all users in role/group
from cmreford1 cmr                                           -- cmreford1: Main table where user/role assignments are stored
join cmobjects cmo on cmr.cmid = cmo.cmid                    -- cmobjects: roles and groups.  groups 26, roles 54
join cmobjnames cmon on cmo.cmid = cmon.cmid                 -- cmobjnames: Role name lookup table     
join cmlocales cml on cmon.mapdlocaleid = cml.mapdlocaleid   -- cmlocales: contains language codes.  Join to objnames for 'en' language filter.
join cmobjprops33 v_user on cmr.refcmid = v_user.cmid        -- cmobjprops33: user table
where 1=1
  and cmo.classid in (26, 54)
  and cml.locale = 'en'
-- and (lower(cmon.name) like '%_edit%'
 --  or lower(cmon.name) like '%_view%'
 --  or lower(cmon.name) like '%_submit%'
-- )
  --and cmon.name = 'Webreporter'  -- Query Specific Groups/roles
 --and v_user.name like '%John%D%'  -- Query specific user names
  --and cmr.propid = 27
  group by cmon.name, v_user.name
  order by cmon.name, v_user.name --cmr.ord desc
;
```

Comment: I can go into the Cognos Administration even without running this SQL query. The goal is exactly to avoid manual checks.

Comment: Join this query with CMPOLICIES.

Comment: As you can see below I found CMPOLICIES table 4 days ago.

Answer (score 0):

Required information is in CMPOLICIES table in BLOB field called POLICIES.
Further BLOB crunching techniques depend on uderlying DB type (Oracle, MSSQL etc.)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't see this mentioned much on the web, but you can use a free **IBM Cognos BI Users and Capabilities Tool** downloadable for **free** at http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24034217. It's a windows java application that's very easy to set up and works quite nicely. I have tested it. It does provide a capability report per user, but I didn't see the role based capability report that I'm pasting the SQL for below.

Another tool that you can use for free is **Motio PI**. This is a free tool that does provide a bunch of information that I found to be ok at first sight. I did not see a role capability report in it either. You have to register to get the tool, but it's painless.

Yet, there's another free tool from IBM called **IBM Cognos 10 Audit Extension** (google it, as I can't paste too many links here yet) It is more involved to install (you have to install it on the server), but I didn't get to run it yet to test it.

Finally, after a few days of hacking, I hope the following sql query works for you. This will list all of the roles, groups with the associated tool and capabilities (secured functions and features). This will *not* show individual user permissions.

You can find the updated SQL at my github repo:
https://github.com/artchik/ccosql